# When I click submit button in my form, create action is supposed to work but it is rather processed by new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, simple-form-for

In my application, I have a form that is supposed to be processed by create action but it is rather processed by new action. This problem is happening in my post task form, but in my other form (registration form), it is working very well (it is processed by create action). So I thought maybe the culprit is in my model relationships so I will post it here as well:

User model

```
has_many :client_relationships, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "client_id", dependent: :destroy

has_many :worker_relationships, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "worker_id", dependent: :destroy

has_many :worker_tasks, through: :client_relationships, source: :worker

has_many :client_tasks, through: :worker_relationships, source: :client
```

Task model

```
belongs_to :client, class_name: "User"

belongs_to :worker, class_name: "User"
```

In my routes.rb

```
resources :users do
  member do
   get :client_tasks, :worker_tasks
   end
  end

resources :tasks
```

If you are wondering, I have two users in tasks table (client_id, worker_id). I have a boolean column in users table to identify them. I also have appointment table which belongs to task but I did not include it here.

Now, after clicking the submit button, Im getting this from cmd:

```
Processing by TasksController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V", "authenticity_token"=>"e5K/I8TpQJwpqGtapZs7xP4n7i3FF
a9xHVSv7CLVYIsYSomK95x6B+J2hSbr77CHvxI01te8hQ7HOGRTRLANNg==", "task"=>{"category
_id"=>"", "title"=>"", "description"=>"", "pay_type"=>"", "pay_offer"=>"", "coun
ty_id"=>"", "area_id"=>"", "appointments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"start_date"=>"", "
start_time"=>"", "end_date"=>"", "end_time"=>""}}}, "commit"=>"Create Task"}
ty_id"=>"", "area_id"=>"", "appointments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"start_date"=>"", "
start_time"=>"", "end_date"=>"", "end_time"=>""}}}, "commit"=>"Create Task"}
```

and im getting this on the browser:

http://localhost:3000/tasks/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=e5K%2FI8TpQJwpqGtapZs7xP4n7i3FFa9xHVSv7CLVYIsYSomK95x6B%2BJ2hSbr77CHvxI01te8hQ7HOGRTRLANNg%3D%3D&task%5Bcategory_id%5D=&task%5Btitle%5D=&task%5Bdescription%5D=&task%5Bpay_type%5D=&task%5Bpay_offer%5D=&task%5Bcounty_id%5D=&task%5Barea_id%5D=&task%5Bappointments_attributes%5D%5B0%5D%5Bstart_date%5D=&task%5Bappointments_attributes%5D%5B0%5D%5Bstart_time%5D=&task%5Bappointments_attributes%5D%5B0%5D%5Bend_date%5D=&task%5Bappointments_attributes%5D%5B0%5D%5Bend_time%5D=&commit=Create+Task

and on the debug message (last 3 lines):

> commit: Create Task
>   controller: tasks
>   action: new

It is supposed to be "action: create" but it is not.

It is really weird, Ive been banging my head all day for this and still can not solve this. I am using simple_form btw. Please help me... I am a newbie here :(

In registration form

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}, wrapper: :horizontal_input_group do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :first_name %>
        <%= f.input :last_name %>
        <%= f.input :email %>
        <%= f.input :password %>
        <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>
        <%= f.input :county_id %>
        <%= f.input :area_id %>
        <%= f.button :submit %>
        <% end %>
```

In post task

```
<%= simple_form_for @task, html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}, wrapper: :horizontal_input_group do |f| %>

        <%= field_set_tag '<span class="label label-info">1</span> What task do you require?'.html_safe do %>
        <%= f.input :category_id, collection: Category.order(:name), label_method: :name, value_method: :id, label: "Category", include_blank: "Select a category of task" %>
        <%= f.input :subcategory_id, collection: Category.order(:name), as: :grouped_select, group_method: :subcategories %>
        <% end %>

        <%= field_set_tag '<span class="label label-info">2</span> Tell us about the task.'.html_safe do %>
        <%= f.input :title, placeholder: 'Give a descriptive title for your task'%>
        <%= f.input :description, placeholder: 'Describe your task here...' %>
        <% end %>

        <%= field_set_tag '<span class="label label-info">3</span> What budget do you have in mind?'.html_safe do %>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="payTypeTabs">
            <%= f.input :pay_type, as: :hidden %>
            <li><a href="#fixed-price-tab" data-toggle="tab">Hire for a fixed price</a></li>
            <li><a href="#per-hour-tab" data-toggle="tab">Hire per hour</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h1></h1>

        <%= f.input :pay_offer, wrapper: :horizontal_input_group do %>
        <span class="input-group-addon">€</span>
        <%= f.input_field :pay_offer, as: :integer, class: "form-control" %>
        <span class="input-group-addon">Euro</span>
        <% end %>

        <% end %>

        <%= field_set_tag '<span class="label label-info">4</span> Where will your task take place?'.html_safe do %>    
        <%= f.input :county_id, collection: County.order(:name), label_method: :name, value_method: :id, label: "County", include_blank: "Select a category of task" %>
        <%= f.input :area_id, collection: County.order(:name), as: :grouped_select, group_method: :areas %>

        <% end %>

        <%= field_set_tag '<span class="label label-info">5</span> Set an initial appointment for this task.'.html_safe, :id => "date_time" do %>
        <% f.simple_fields_for :appointments do |b| %>


        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2"><%= b.input :start_date, label: "Start", wrapper: :horizontal_input_group do %>

                <%= b.input_field :start_date, placeholder: 'Start date', class: "form-control date start" %><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>


                <% end %>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5"><%= b.input :start_time, label: false, wrapper: :horizontal_input_group do %>


                <%= b.input_field :start_time, placeholder: 'Start time', as: :string, class: "form-control time start" %><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></span>

                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
                <%= b.input :end_date, label: "End", wrapper: :horizontal_input_group do %>
                <%= b.input_field :end_date, placeholder: 'End date', class: "form-control date end" %>
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                <% end %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <%= b.input :end_time, label: false, wrapper: :horizontal_input_group do %>

                <%= b.input_field :end_time, placeholder: 'End time', as: :string, class: "form-control time end" %>
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></span>
                <% end %>
            </div>

            <% end %>
            <% end %>

            <%= f.button :submit %>
            <% end %>
```

Comment: Also if you are wondering, I already have defined the actions in taskcontrollers.

Comment: can you provide the form_for code for both the post task and registration forms ? As far as i can see the routes are defined properly. should be an issue with the form_for

Comment: your second form does not have the simple_form_for start tag. can you edit it to show that ? have a feeling that's where the change should happen

Comment: Sorry bout that. please see the updated edits agains.

Comment: in my second form (registration), I already tried running it without all div tags. and it still doesnt solve the issue :'(

Comment: div tags should not affect the way form is submitted. check my answer and see if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really weird that it works in the first case and not in the second.

Try this,

```
<%= simple_form_for @task, url: tasks_path, method: :post, html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}, wrapper: :horizontal_input_group do |f| %>
```

this will force the form to submit to tasks_path with post method which goes to the create action. Let me know if it works

Also, this is your create method

```
        def create 
            @task = current_user.client_relationships.build(task_params) 
            if @task.save 
                flash[:success] = "Micropost created!" 
                redirect_to @current_user 
            else 
                render 'new' 
            end 
        end
```

A couple of issues.

1) redirect_to @current_user does not mean anything, right ? should be like user_path(@current_user)

2) you should always do redirect_to  and return so that the code block after redirection will not be called. In your case, its ok since the rest is in a else block

3) It could be that task.save fails and new is rendered. use a debugger and check if comes to first line of create

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your solution but still no luck.. :(

Comment: here's a couple of things to try, 1) f.submit instead of f.button 2)make sure you have resources :tasks in your routes.rb and you have restarted your server. can you tell me what @task is ? where it is defined and the tasks_controller.rb code ?

Comment: and when you make these modifications refresh the page and see the html code. It should be like <form action="/tasks" method="post"> . . .

Comment: I already have tried your suggestion 1 and 2. Ok, I have this:           class TasksController < ApplicationController
 def new
  "@"task = current_user.client_relationships.build if logged_in?
  "@"task.appointments.build
 end

 def create
  "@"task = current_user.client_relationships.build(task_params)
  if "@"task.save
   flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
   redirect_to "@"current_user
  else
   render 'new'
  end
 end

 private
 def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:category, :subcategory)
 end
end

Comment: pls take note i only put the quotes between the char @ as it doesnt let me comment here.

Comment: I checked the html source code, I have this code:  action="/tasks" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">      but the color is highlighted to red, I compared it to registration form, and the color is normal black. its really weird :(

Comment: do you see a hidden input tag with authenticity token just below the form tag ? there should be one for every post calls.

Comment: one clear difference between the two forms you have posted is that one of it updates only one model while the one that does not work updates associated models. but i m not sure why it would not work with multiple models.

Comment: yes! <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="UK3d0JuxslHzCkN7uJ9O1uIHVB7OFBcZ+Znkj7soL5Izdet5qMSIyjjUrQf268WVozKO5dy9PWYj9S8w3U1CLw==" />

Comment: Hi, tnx again for your answer. Ive done all things you've suggested and few other things, I even took out the create method and expected an error (ie: unknown action), but it did not have any error. Its giving me the same behaviour. huhuhu

Comment: sad! I do not have my development environment setup to debug deeper. I'm afraid i'm out of options. Hope someone else helps you out. update the question or comment when you find the answer. all the best. my best bet would be updating associated models is the culprit

Comment: I will! :) this is weirdest problem ive ever encounterd in my life. lol. Thank you for your help and time.