# Create action in controller not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form-for

It is very basic but I am stuck. I have a form that does not processed by create action, rather it is processed by new action. Please see my same post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684567/when-i-click-submit-button-in-my-form-create-action-is-supposed-to-work-but-it). I am just creating this new post to emphasize my strange problem:

in my taskscontroller, I removed the create action so I am expecting an error like this:

> The action 'create' could not be found for TasksController

Surprisingly, it is not giving any errors. After clicking submit, the url looks like this: http://localhost:3000/tasks/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=McuQZLyQrDCkgBV4ur0yIp4%2BhyDBRXYEcXSmD7sR4c%2B2X61ay9SqE5jrpN8q64TEk2AxR5WGTuo7ofAZoRib3w%3D%3D&task%5Bcategory_id%5D=&task%5Btitle%5D=&task%5Bdescription%5D=&task%5Bpay_type%5D=&task%5Bpay_offer%5D=&task%5Bcounty_id%5D=&task%5Barea_id%5D=&task%5Bappointments_attributes%5D%5B0%5D%5Bstart_date%5D=&task%5Bappointments_attributes%5D%5B0%5D%5Bstart_time%5D=&task%5Bappointments_attributes%5D%5B0%5D%5Bend_date%5D=&task%5Bappointments_attributes%5D%5B0%5D%5Bend_time%5D=&commit=Create+Task

and on the debug message (last 3 lines):

```
commit: Create Task 
controller: tasks 
action: new
```

The action is supposed to be:

```
action: create
```

but its not.

Please see my full post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684567/when-i-click-submit-button-in-my-form-create-action-is-supposed-to-work-but-it). Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this will work but you probably should try to fix a path / url in this case. I'm not familiar with simple form, but it should be something like in this post: https://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=h17sVMmyM8uGuATcx4KoBw&url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507633/how-to-define-action-with-simple-form-for&ved=0CB4QFjAA&usg=AFQjCNEgz64JN8rSInstdB9teA9gelELnw

Comment: tried that already. no luck. tnx for the reply

Comment: Did you verify if your save was successful? It seems you are rendering "new" if your save fails. If the first case isn't the problem, then it should be your save failing.